# Android Market: Comments not consistent

Tags: google-play-store

I've noticed that for each app i see different comments if i'm going from the web version or mobile version of the market althought I click "Read All User Reviews" on both.

Have you also noticed this?

What is the reason?!

App: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vodafone.mCare

Web Version: http://d.pr/WJz5 (Logged with my Google Account)

Mobile Version: http://d.pr/ldxN (Logged with other Google Account)

Ps: Nevermind the language, it's portuguese, it's an example.

**UPDATE:**

I've confirmed it has to do with the Google account that you'r logged in. But what are the criteria?! Shouldn't we all see the same?! (at least if we're not the app owner).

Comment: Good question. I have seen it to. Me and my friends does not necessarily see the same comments for an app in the market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I found a even more strange thing. The differences are **due to the language**.

If I set my browser language to portuguese suddently I see all the comments that I saw on the other account (that I was seeing on an Android device set to Portuguese). This is very strange as all comments are written in Portuguese. I haven't discovered yet how they associate the language to the comment...

My **guess**:

Comments are only visible on the language that they are added. For example: (this is a guess)

- If i add a comment with my browser in Portuguese, only people with
  browsers/devices in Portuguese will see it

Shouldn't the market show all anyway, with somekind of language filter (our language vs all) or use Google Translate to translate all from the start?

*Does anyone else has a clue about this?!*

Comment: Your assertion is correct. As a Android developer, I can see *all* comments for my app (in the Google's Android app management interface), and many of them are *not* in English. I can see only English comments on my phone. Auto-translating comments is not viable as the translation technology is not quite there yet.

Comment: They are already doing something similar on Google Moderator... it's not perfect but i think it's better than this.

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN: current computer translations requires text with reasonably good spelling and grammar; with the market comment having very limited space, many people would use textspeak or unusual sentence constructions to so their comment would fit while many others would just do so out of habit or laziness. I think it would be quite hard but interesting problem when computer translation reaches the stage where it can handle such things.